# Color a large point cloud using height value in VTK

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, point-clouds, colormap

I am using VTK python bindings to color a large point cloud based on the height of the points. I am able to color them properly using `vtk.vtkLookupTable`, and looping through all the points and getting color based on z value using `GetColor` function, but looping through large number of points is very slow. 
Below mentioned code will show how i did that 
**Code :**

```
lookUpTable = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lookUpTable.SetTableRange(minz,maxz)
lookUpTable.Build()

# Create a unsigned char array to color
uCharArray = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
uCharArray.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
uCharArray.SetName("colors")
```

After we have created `LookupTable` and `UnsignedCharArray`, i am looping through all the points and filling up the above defined array.

```
# Assign color by extracting each color
for i in range(outputPolyData.GetNumberOfPoints()):
    point = outputPolyData.GetPoint(i)
    # Get the color from lookup table
    color = [0]*3
    lookUpTable.GetColor(point[2],color)
    # Convert each color to 255
    for j in range(len(color)):
        color[j] = int(255 * color[j])
    uCharArray.InsertTypedTuple(i,color)


# # Set Scalars
outputPolyData.GetPointData().SetScalars(uCharArray)
```

The output will be 
[image]

But to color `1000000` points, its taking 3.180 seconds. I actually have 8000000 points. It would take a lot of time if i loop over every point to assign color.
I am pretty sure there would be other way to do this. If any one can point me in the right direction, i would be glad.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using `MapScalars` function in `vtkLookupTable`. This function is used inside the class to generate lookup tables.
I passed the `Z` array to the function, it gave me an array of colors.

```
array = lookUpTable.MapScalars(vtkzArray,vtk.VTK_COLOR_MODE_DEFAULT,-1)
outputPolyData.GetPointData().SetScalars(array)
```

Here `vtkzArray` should be of type `vtkDataArray`. I converted numpy array to `vtkDataArray` using `vtk_to_numpy` from numpy_support class.